# Library method for seconds elapsed since start of year

Tags: ruby

I want to calculate the number of seconds elapsed since the start of the current year. A straightforward approach would be to get the current date and the date on the start of the year and subtract the two but I was wondering if there was a library method that could do that for me.

This would help my year to date calculations look prettier.

Answer (score 1):

```
current_time = Time.new
current_time - Time.new(current_time.year)
```

This will return a Float of the number of seconds since the start of the current year. See [Time](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Time.html) for more information.